# Lithium Mongodb error on remote connection

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

I have the following issue with Lithium. When I connect to mongodb on my localhost all works well, but when I connect to my remote mongodb on EC2 it gives me the following error:

*Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'Operation now in progress' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/v0.4/libraries/lithium/data/source/MongoDb.php:430*

Both mongodb versions are the same (1.8.0) and I can connect to my remote mongodb with the shell. I'm running lithium 0.9.9, mongo php driver 1.1.4 and php version 5.3.4, on Mac osx snow leopard.

Any suggestions?

Update: I have tried with the latest master version, but still have the error. You can view my full stack trace here: http://pastium.org/view/90c1dd7201eca845913c4101a205a023

Comment: It turned out to be the default timeout was set to 100, and due to my high network latency the connection failed.

Comment: It looked to be something like that, don't hesitate to ask your questions on the IRC channel: `irc://irc.freenode.net/#li3`

Answer (score 1):

This error is often associated with a timeout of the connection to the database.

This is more likely to happen when the web-server and the MongoDB server are on different hosts, networks, or providers (like EC2 in your case) due to network latency ...

The default timeout set in Lithium is `100 ms`, which can be too slow for some network configurations (however it should generally be perfectly fine.)

This is documented here: [Lithium MongoDB Adapter](http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/data/source/MongoDb::__construct%28%29)

[image: Lithium MongoDB Adapter timeout setting]

You can see the default MongoDB connection configuration in Lithium here: (line 153 at this time) ...

https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/data/source/MongoDb.php

From the comments on that page,

> `'timeout'` *integer*: The number of milliseconds a connection attempt will wait
>   before timing out and throwing an exception.
>
> Defaults to `100`